# Highcharts pie chart outer circle

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to add a circle around a pie chart in highcharts?

I know I can do it with an absolute positioned div just over the size of the chart, with a negative zIndex, but it doesn't look entirely right since the graph is drawn with SVG (notice the slight offset on the attached image where I've tried that approach

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a shadow with a 0 offset.
http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/RgdJ3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        plotOptions: {  
            pie: {
                shadow: {
                    color: 'black', 
                    offsetX : 0,
                    offsetY: 0,
                    opacity: 1,
                    width: 3
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   44.2],
                ['IE7',       26.6],
                ['IE6',       20],
                ['Chrome',    3.1],
                ['Other',    5.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: This is absolutely better than what I had, thanks!  There's a slight blip at the top, but overall great